# What is the purpose of the howMany integer in the wire.onReceive() function from the example code?

Tags: i2c

In the master write/ slave read example for the wire library, there is an integer declared howMany that is never used.

```
 void setup() {
   Wire.begin(8);                // join i2c bus with address #8
   Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
   Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  while (1 < Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
   char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
   Serial.print(c);         // print the character
}
 int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
 Serial.println(x); 
}
```

As the function does not work without it, i would like to know what is its exact purpose.I would imagine that is something regarding the buffer size.

Comment: The description of the wire commands are extremly poor. For me there is also a lot of guessing involved. Without example codes from foren for me it is not possible to generate a running code.
For that reason the question for the sense of how many is very valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells you how many bytes have been received, and consequently how many you can read with `Wire.read()`.

Before you have read anything with `Wire.read()` `Wire.available()` will return the same value.  As you read from the buffer `Wire.available()` will decrease, but `howMany` will stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

The reference page https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireOnReceive states:

> Parameters
>
> handler: the function to be called when the slave receives data; this should take a single int parameter (the number of bytes read from the master) and return nothing, e.g.: `void myHandler(int numBytes)`

I suggest you look at the reference pages for the functions in future before asking what they do.